# Why DexClassLoader is having API level 3, and its base class is having API level 14

Tags: android

I was wondering, why [DexClassLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html) is having API level 3, and its base class [BaseDexClassLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/BaseDexClassLoader.html) is having API level 14?

How can a child class exist, even before its parent class exist?

Comment: Are you using the android-support-v# libs? I may have had a similar issue once because I had two support libs in the project that conflicted. Also, a little more info on the project and problem may help with an answer.